# Can a pthread perform clean-up on its own?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Let's say I:

- `malloc` a `pthread_t`for holding a thread context
- `pthread_create` with as user parameter the pointer to the `pthread_t` structure

In other words, the thread function has access to its `pthread_t` context structure. Now here is the tricky bit:

**How can the pthread exit on its own and get the `pthread_t` context freed somehow?** i.e. is it possible **not** to involve the parent thread? (no mutex/join etc.)

**Think of this as a "lightweight process".**

(and no the thread cannot `free()` the structure just before exiting its `thread_func`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `pthread_t` you receive when creating a thread is merely its ID, used to refer to that thread from other threads.

To have the thread context freed automatically when the thread terminates, you should detach it from the parent thread using `pthread_detach()`

If you pass a pointer to the `pthread_t` returned from the initial `pthread_create()`, you could simply `free()` it immediately in the new thread's start routine. If you need to refer to the `pthread_t` value for the current thread again, just call `pthread_self()`. However it would be much easier to allocate `pthread_t` on the stack in the parent thread, and not bother to pass it to the child thread at all (or rather pass something more useful).

```
void *child_routine(void *arg)
{
    pthread_t thread = pthread_self();
}

void parent()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, child_routine, NULL);
    pthread_detach(thread);
}
```

Comment: @Anacrolix:  Thanks!  I feel so dumb: I should have checked the header file (`typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;`).

Comment: i just appreciate people asking real questions about decent platforms and languages :)

Comment: @jldupont: `pthread_t` can be a pointer or a structure as well.

Comment: Another option is to create the thread in a detached state from the beginning: see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads for using pthread_attr_setdetachstate() to initialize a pthread_attr_t object and passing it as the 'attr' argument to pthread_create()